# SQL Merge output both matched and unmatched results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two keys for data, *pk* is supposed to be generated from database when a row is inserted, while *fk* is a complex key which is given by another system. I would like to produce a *pk* key for each *fk* key.

```
CREATE TABLE test_target (
[pk] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1),
[fk] [varchar](20) NOT NULL)
```

And I can use merge to ensure that a new *pk* is produced whenever there is no corresponding *fk* exists in the table and I know I can output the newly created ids.

```
CREATE TABLE test_source (
[fk] [varchar](20) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO test_source VALUES('abc123'),('def456'),('ghi789')

MERGE test_target WITH (SERIALIZABLE) AS T
USING test_source AS U
ON U.fk = T.fk
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (fk) VALUES(U.fk)
OUTPUT inserted.pk, inserted.fk;
```

However, what I really want is **all** the *pk* associated with the *fk* in the test_source table. So I can get all by joining two tables.

```
SELECT test_target.* FROM test_target
INNER JOIN test_source ON test_target.fk = test_source.fk
```

But I feel like the associate *pk* is already found when in the case of MATCHED in the merge statement, so it is duplicated effort to do another search on the target table. My question is that is there a way to output the MATCHED *pk* in the same merge statement?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You want some kind of product specific functionality.)

Comment: Given the query hint, I would suggest SQL Server

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is - at first I thought I had to touch the row and update it in some form but I've realized we can just trick it. The output clause will output any row the statement touches, not just the rows you did not match on, so you can include a when matched clause - the problem is to make it a null op.

```
create table foo
(
    id int
    ,bar varchar(30)
)

insert into foo (id, bar) values (1,'test1');
insert into foo (id, bar) values (2,'test2');
insert into foo (id, bar) values (3,'test3');

declare @temp int;
merge foo as dest
using
(
    values (2, 'an updated value')
        , (4, 'a new value')
) as src(id, bar) on (dest.id = src.id)
when matched then
update set @temp=1
when not matched then
insert (id,bar)
values (src.id, src.bar)
output $action, src.id;
```

You can see in the when matched clause, I set a declared variable to 1. This is oddly enough to be considered for the output clause to pick it up for output. You can distinguish which operation (insert vs update) has occurred if you need with the $action in the output.

This gives the following results:

```
$action     id
UPDATE  2
INSERT  4
```

Performance wise I'd want to test how to operated at scale, or whether the variable assignment would cause a throttling effect

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that instead of updating a temp value, it is possible to update a temp table when it is matched but I am not able to do it.